# Group Theory Subgroups

Tags: group-theory

If $H$ and $K$ are subgroups of a group $G$, is H$\cup K$ necessarily a subgroup of $G$?

My attempt:
I made up two subgroups, H and K of G.

$H=\{a^{-1},e,a\}$ and $K=\{b^{-1},e,b\}$ 
But then I assumed a,b$\in H\cup K$ and since $a\in H$ and $b\in K$ then $a*b$ doesn't have to belong in $H$ or $K$ as maybe we have $F=\{(a*b)^{-1},e,(a*b)\}$
Is there a better way of writing this out, if right? Thanks.

Comment: Hint:  try simple examples.  Like the non-cyclic group of order $4$.

Comment: @Lulu thanks, what is meant by non-cyclic order 4?

Comment: $\Bbb Z/2 \times \Bbb Z/2$. It's unique group with 4 elements that is not cyclic.

Comment: This is an important example to learn.  It's the smallest non-cyclic group (though it is abelian).  Very useful for testing things.

Comment: You have to be careful with your example. If $a=b$, then $H\cup K$ is a subgroup trivially. However, if $a\neq b$, we still don't necessarily have two disjoint subgroups, because we would also have to rule out the possibility that $a=b^{-1}$ (in that case we would again have $H=K$). However, if $a\neq b$ and $a\neq b^{-1}$, then we can't have $ab\in H\cup K$, because, say, $ab\in H$, then $a^{-1}ab=b\in H$, contrary to our assumptions (the other case is analogous).

Comment: @ShaVuklia true! I was  trying to say that a and  b $\in$ to different groups

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Proposition** Let $H, K$ be subgroups of a group $G$, then $H \cup K$ is a subgroup of $G$ if and only if $H \subseteq K$ or $K \subseteq H$.

**Proof** The only if side is trivial. Assume that $H \nsubseteq K$ and $K \nsubseteq H$. Then we can find an $h \in H$ with $h \notin K$ and symmetrically, a $k \in K$ witk $k \notin H$. Now look at $hk$. Certainly, since $H \cup K$ is a subgroup, $hk \in H \cup K$. So $hk \in H$ or $hk \in K$. If $hk \in H$, say $hk=h'$, then $k=h^{-1}h' \in H$ a contradiction. Similarly, $hk \in K$ leads to a contradiction.

Comment: This proposition is also true for module. It is just extra information :).

Answer (score 0):

Let $G=(\Bbb Z, +)$.

You can think $3\Bbb Z\cup 5\Bbb Z$.

$3\in 3\Bbb Z\cup 5\Bbb Z$ and $5\in3\Bbb Z\cup 5\Bbb Z$, but $3-5=-2\notin  3\Bbb Z\cup 5\Bbb Z$.

Hence, the union of two subgroups does not have to be a subgroup.

Comment: is 3$\Bb$Z={-3,0,3}? sorry never seen this notation before

Comment: Yes, it is similar your guess. $3\Bbb Z=\{\cdots, -6, -3, 0, 3, 6, \cdots \}=\{3k:k\in \Bbb Z\}$

Comment: I want to give an example for propositon given by @Nicky. Just think $2\Bbb Z \cup 4\Bbb Z$.

Comment: this example makes it all easier to see, thanks